# Как сделать возможность загрузки и удаления фото на сайт

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Мне необходимо реализовать верстку загрузки и удаления фото с сайта. Выглядит это так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть человек нажимает на загрузку, загружает файл, также он может его удалить

Как это сделать? Знаю плагин dropzonejs, но не знаю как реализовать внешний вид

Comment: Сталкивался с этим давно, сейчас не помню как делать.
Почитай про Drag and Drop и FilleReader

Comment: У вас с вёрсткой проблемы или с загрузкой файлов на сайт? Если с вёрсткой, то причём здесь загрузка? И на оборот.

Comment: У меня не получается стилизовать dropzonejs как на картинке